# Radio Button needs to be clicked twice to change the second time with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I click on any radio input the first time it works (meaning I only have to click once). When I click on the second radio input I have to do it twice to change it. How do I fix it?

```
export default function RadioInput() {
    const { register, setValue } = useForm<FormData>();
    const [inputValue1, setInputValue1] = useState('');
    const [inputValue2, setInputValue2] = useState('');
    const [isSelected1, setIsSelected1] = useState(false);
    const [isSelected2, setIsSelected2] = useState (false);
    const onChange1 = () => {
        console.log(inputValue1)
        setInputValue1(inputValue1)
        setIsSelected1(!isSelected1)
    };
    const onChange2 = () => {
        console.log(inputValue2)
        setInputValue2(inputValue2)
        setIsSelected2(!isSelected2)
    };
    const styles = {
        radioPink: {
            border: "10px solid green"
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <label className="radio">Company
                <input type="radio" checked={isSelected1} value={inputValue1} onChange=. 
                    {onChange1} name="is_company"/>
                    <span className="checkround"/>
            </label>
            <label className="radio">Company
                <input type="radio" checked={isSelected2} value={inputValue2} onChange= 
                    {onChange2} name="is_company"/>
                    <span className="checkround"/>
            </label>
            <button className="btn cust-btn " type="button" id="btn-registration"
                    >Register
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a radio control, there can only be one selected option. As such, it only needs one piece of state. As it currently is, you could potentially have both radio options set to `true`! Let's refactor to only have one piece of state control this input group.

```
export default function RadioInput() {
    const { register, setValue } = useForm<FormData>();
    const [inputValue1, setInputValue1] = useState('');
    const [inputValue2, setInputValue2] = useState('');
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

    const onChange1 = () => {
        console.log(inputValue1)
        setInputValue1(inputValue1)
        setSelected(1)
    };
    const onChange2 = () => {
        console.log(inputValue2)
        setInputValue2(inputValue2)
        setSelected(2)
    };
    const styles = {
        radioPink: {
            border: "10px solid green"
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <label className="radio">Company
                <input type="radio" checked={selected === 1} value={inputValue1} onChange={onChange1} name="is_company"/>
                <span className="checkround"/>
            </label>
            <label className="radio">Company
                <input type="radio" checked={selected === 2} value={inputValue2} onChange={onChange2} name="is_company"/>
                <span className="checkround"/>
            </label>
            <button className="btn cust-btn " type="button" id="btn-registration"
                    >Register
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I added a better option but it is still acting out, now it selects the opposite radio the first time I click on it

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, I didn't understand initially that you made changes.